# How to grant IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool access to stored procedures in Asp.net using IIS?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008, iis-7.5

Here is the error message I get, "The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'GetDepartments', database 'BalloonShop', schema 'dbo"

I was able to workaround it by configuring sql server 2008 and making IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool a dbowner aside from datawriter and datareader, the problem is there are some security issues with it according to some articles that I found online.

How do I allow  IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool to have access to all stored procs in my current database?(or in any database)

(It would be nice if you could provide links/ script)

Sir/Ma'am your answers would be of great help. Thank you++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use below script to grant execute permissions on a schema

```
grant  execute on schema :: dbo to username
```

Comment: I tried using grant execute on schema :: BalloonShop to [IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool] but I get this error "Cannot find the schema 'BalloonShop', because it does not exist or you do not have permission." I tried using 'use BalloonShop' but it's not working. :D

Comment: BaloonShop is the database.. schema is dbo. so use this   **grant  execute on schema :: dbo to  [IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool]**

Comment: ok so, just to make it clear will IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool be able to run all stored procs in sql server, because what I wanted to do was just to allow defaulapppool to have access to BalloonShop database. :D

Comment: by using above statement you are granting access to dbo schema. If you want to be able to execute all SPs, you will have to grant access on ALL schemas one by one..